# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 17): FA-LA-LA-LA-LA LA-LA-LA-LA

Tags: word, knowledge, music, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd><Previous Door</kbd>](/q/124692)[<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124727/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-18-a-holly-jolly-hexologic)</sub>

---

Mr. Slant, our old-school, puzzling choirmaster, picked a good variety of Christmas carols for today’s service, including old favourites as well as less-know works by Skoog and Winkworth.  He told us that we should work out the eighth hymn from the first seven, but while hurrying to the service, I slipped on the ice and scattered the carols! To make matters worse, I had foolishly only noted down the solfege of the first lines of each carol…

- DO DO DO RE DO DO SO // LA SO LA TI DO DO
- DO RE MI LA SO SO // SO SO SO MI RE MI SO SO SO MI RE MI
- MI RE DO LA TI DO TI LA // MI RE DO LA TI DO TI LA
- SO DO DO DO TI LA SO FA MI // SO FA FA FA MI RE MI
- SO DO DO TI DO MI MI RE // SO SO SO FA MI RE MI
- SO LA SO MI SO LA SO MI // RE RE TI DO DO SO
- LA LA LA SO LA DO TI LA // LA TI DO RE DO RE RE MI

Can you work out what the 8th hymn should be?

HINT (20231218):

> Mr Slant also works as a Latin teacher and was keen to point out that the Winkworth carol is an English translation of a German translation of a Latin piece by St. Ambrose. The carol with words by Dante's sister has a number of arrangements.

HINT (20231219):

> As a classicist Mr *Slant* is familiar with the [ISIS puzzle format](https://www.mit.edu/%7Edwilson/puzzles/puzzlewriting.html). He also knew that the puzzle had an appropriate day (but the year being a 50th and 10th anniversary passed him by).

HINT (20231220):

> In the chapel (which Mr Slant had kept at a brisk 45 degrees), he said "If your sheets get out of order, remember that the carols come in the same order as in the back of the hymn book."
>  One of the choir seemed to be making better progress: "Ah! Of course, he's using the Latin alphabet."

Comment: Thats a carol...

Comment: I have 5/7 melodies identified. I almost have a perfect match for the second one except for the “fa re” at the end. Is that definitely right? (The other one I don’t have is the last one)

Comment: @caPNCApn It seems that there are a lot of arrangements and parts to the second carol. I've now changed to something that seems a bit more consensus.

Comment: The hints helped me get the first seven hymns, now need to work out the eighth...

Comment: @fljx now, are you able to post a partial answer?

Comment: I got all the hymns I just don’t know what to do with them lol

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker rot13(Guvf glcr bs chmmyr vf xabja nf na VFVF chmmyr (Vqragvsl - Fbeg - Vaqrk - Fbyir). Lbh unir Vqragvsvrq gur pnebyf, abj Fbeg gurz gura Vaqrk vagb gurz gb rkgenpg yrggref naq Fbyir.)

Comment: Yeah I figured that out lol

Comment: Tried pretty much everything can’t get the answer I’m tapping out for now lol

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Took a bit of time but with today's clue, I think I've got a solution.
The carols are spoilered separately at first for anyone who wants to check without seeing my other identifications.

First, we start by converting the Solfege into the carols:

> 1. Good king Wenceslas

> 2. Love came down at Christmas

> 3. We three kings of orient are

> 4. Our day of joy is here again

> 5. Hark! The herald angels sing

> 6. Silent night, Holy night

> 7. Redeemer of the nations, come

Next, sort them into

> Alphabetical order:
>
>  - Good king Wenceslas
>  - Hark! The herald angels sing
>  - Love came down at Christmas
>  - Our day of joy is here again
>  - Redeemer of the nations, come
>  - Silent night, Holy night
>  - We three kings of orient are

and extract letters by

> Removing punctuation and spacing, and reading diagonally downwards, in keeping with the Professor's name and preferred temperature:
>
>  `Goodkingwenceslas`
>  `hArktheheraldangelssing`
>  `loVecamedownatchristmas`
>  `ourDayofjoyishereagain`
>  `redeEmerofthenationscome`
>  `silenTnightholynight`
>  `WethreEkingsoforientare`

to give us

> GAVDETE in [Classical Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet#Classical_Latin_alphabet)

So the 8th carol must be

> *Gaudete, gaudete! Christus est natus*
>  which is only appropriate for [Gaudete Sunday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaudete_Sunday) - credit to @Stiv for the connection

Comment: Oh damn I so close!!

Comment: I just thought it was a nonsense word well done!!

Comment: Yeah, it was the hint about the latin alphabet that made me try reading it all in caps for the final step

Comment: @Falsesummer Bravo and many thanks for the persistence! Did you work out why the day was appropriate and what the anniversaries are?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that was the one piece of your clues that I didn't get an answer for.

Comment: Ah well done - all I was missing was the final extraction, which I didn't think of because it wasn't square! The link you need for the date relies on the fact that rot13(Gur guveq Fhaqnl va Nqirag vf Tnhqrgr Fhaqnl)

Comment: @Falsesummer Also, [from 1973](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTbq2pPLW6I) and [from 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grVrDsqQdXc)

Comment: @Stiv Ah, very clever! I'll add that to my answer with credit, if you don't mind.

Comment: @DanielS As something of a classicist myself, I feel in good company with Prof. Slant by missing those two!