# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 18): A holly jolly Hexologic

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124699/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-17-fa-la-la-la-la-la-la-la-la) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/pse-advent-calendar-2023-day-19-a-christmas-family-union)</sub>

---

**Rules:**

> Normal Hexologic rules apply
>
> - You can place one, two or three dots in each blank space.
> - The number value of the cells in a given row must add up to the number that is pointing towards that row.
> - If you put a number in a colored cell, then all cells that are colored the same color also have that number.
> - Numbers that are greater than 3 that are already on the grid are forced numbers that are already part of the puzzle.

##### [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1qlzfrlza7)<sup>{1}</sup>

##### [Desmos link for partially colorblind puzzlers](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6s1te1fkk6)

---

[image]

---

For partially colorblind puzzlers (hue is changed from 0.4 to 0.7)

[image]

---

<sub><sup>{1}</sup>only thing that I found that would let me place proper hexagons tbh</sub>

Comment: I hate to say it, but there aren't any arrows in the image.

Comment: @fljx sorry about that, I was for some reason unable to make that work. I've been attempting to fix it on a copy but am unable to for some reason

Comment: It's fairly clear which rows the numbers should be pointing at. But your instructions mention arrows.

Comment: @fljx yeah, i know, I'll fix the wording quick

Comment: I don't think this is solvable as-is. The down-left 13 requires 8 from 3 unknown cells, which must be 2,3,3 in some order. But the 3 in the second column from the left requires all 1's.

Comment: @fljx Thanks for that comment, I just realized that I accidentally counted something incorrectly, whoops

Comment: The down-right 11 is also problematic...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150397/discussion-between-crsb0001-and-fljx).

Comment: "If you put a number in a colored cell, then all cells that are colored the same color also have that number. Numbers that are greater than 3 that are already on the grid are forced numbers that are already part of the puzzle." That'd imply all already-numbered cells of the same color have the same number. They don't.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh sorry about that, I was trying to go with a Christmas theme tbh, I could try making the cells brighter (since I know that's possible using Desmos)

Comment: @CrSb0001: Ah, Christmas of course. Is it possible to change the borders? Dash/Dotted vs plain to distinguish red from green would work quite well. Otherwise, if possible, a different hue would help indeed, making one lighter and one darker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The completed tree:

> [image]

The solve path:

> The 6 column on the left must have a 3 in both cells.
>
> And the adjacent 3 column must have a 1 in every cell.
>
> That makes all the green cells 1.
>
> The down-left 20 now needs another 6 from two cells, so both must be 3.
>
> And that makes all the red cells 3.
>
> And the down-right 10 has one unknown cell that must be a 3.
>  [image]

> The 5 column on the right has one unknown cell that must be a 2.
>
> The down-left 9 has one unknown cell that must be a 2.
>
> That makes all the blue cells 2.
>
> And now the up-left 10 has one unknown cell that must be 1.
>
> And the down-left 12 has one unknown cell that must be 2.
>  [image]

> The up-right 9 has one unknown cell that must be 3.
>
> And now the big 27 column has one unknown cell that must be 2.
>
> The 11 column has one unknown cell that must be 3.
>
> And finally, the last empty cell must be 1 to complete the down-right 12.
>  [image]