# PSE Advent Calendar 2023 (Day 19): A Christmas Family Union

Tags: cryptic-clues, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2023](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7527). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124727) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](/questions/124747)</sub>

---

In the style of the author's [Cryptic Family Reunion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=cryptic+family+reunion) puzzles, this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words, phrases or proper names, each clued cryptically, with the theme to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member to stand in for the definition part of the clue. As an additional solving help, the clues are listed with their answers in alphabetic order. I hope you enjoy!

1. Mother turning over a new leaf, shaken after losing first-born's hat (6)
2. Father's drinks, stirred with a bit of ice and tonic, providing a refreshment in goblet after discarding ice (11)
3. Daddy-O rockin' a cover of Kuiama, First Movement of ELO with father (5,6)
4. Father confused after changing direction in Danzig, or later (8)
5. Father's mad; shoe broke on its introduction to foot (5-4)
6. German Jews embraced the French man as father (10)
7. Father flipped three Kalashnikovs, including two of old and a new (10)
8. Look over, up, over, up, left, and left for father (7)
9. Father Lee prone to convert (4,4)
10. A stalker in disguise primarily shadows father (11)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The family are all

> international folklore figures who bring gifts at Christmas

In order

> 1. Mother turning over a new leaf, shaken after losing first-born's hat (6)
> [BEFANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befana) (Italy) ((A N _EAF)*+B)<

> 2. Father's drinks, stirred with a bit of ice and tonic, providing a refreshment in goblet after discarding ice (11)
> [CHRISTKINDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christkind) (Austria, Switzerland, Czech Republic) (DRINKS + I + T)* in CH(-A)L(-ICE)

> 3. Daddy-O rockin' a cover of Kuiama, First Movement of ELO with father (5,6)
> [DYADO KOLEDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ded_Moroz#Bulgaria) (Bulgaria)  ((DADDY O)* + A) covers K_ + (ELO)*

> 4. Father confused after changing direction in Danzig, or later (8)
> [GWIAZDOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observance_of_Christmas_by_country#Poland) (Poland) (DANZIG)* with W for N + OR

> 5. Father's mad; shoe broke on its introduction to foot (5-4)
> [HOTEI OSHO](http://www.santas.net/japanesechristmas.htm) (Japan) HOT + (SHOE)* around I_ + _O

> 6. German Jews embraced the French man as father (10)
> [JULEMANDEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julemanden) (Denmark) JUDEN around LE MAN

> 7. Father flipped three Kalashnikovs, including two of old and a new (10)
> [KANAKALOKA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_in_Hawaii#Celebrations_today) (Hawai'i) (AK AK AK around A N and OL_)<

> 8. Look over, up, over, up, left, and left for father (7) 
> [KRAMPUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krampus) (Germany) MARK< + UP< + S (North, turn left, turn left is South)
> As the above is wrong, my next best guess is [MIKULAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Nicholas_(European_folklore)) (Hungary) SKIM< over U + L + A_

> 9. Father Lee prone to convert (4,4)
> [PERE NOEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A8re_No%C3%ABl) (France) (LEE PRONE)*

> 10. A stalker in disguise primarily shadows father (11)
> [SINTERKLAAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinterklaas) (Netherlands) (A STALKER IN)* + S_

Comment: Mostly correct! However I don't think your #8 wordplay works, since it needs to re-use at least one of the lefts at the end; at least, this was not the intended answer. Also the wordplay for #1 is incomplete, since it does not explain how rot13(gur O trgf gb gur ortvaavat bs gur nafjre). Also, the wordplay on #4 is also a bit more subtle than you've explained.

Comment: Could you include the clues in the answer, to save a bunch of scrolling?

Comment: @fljx Done (+comment padding).

Comment: @JeremyDover I've modified some of the answers, but am confused over #8: there are two lefts and I used them both once.

Comment: OK, I think I understand where you're coming from, but a couple of objections: rot13(lbh erdhver ZNEX nf n flabalz sbe YBBX, juvpu frrzf grahbhf gb zr) and more importantly, rot13(gur bgure nafjref [naq gur vagraqrq urer] unir n pybfre pbaarpgvba guna lbh unir fgngrq, gung XENZCHF qbrf abg funer). The other corrections are what I had in mind...thank you!

Comment: @JeremyDover: A different idea now in place (though the formatter seems to have become confused)

Comment: That is correct! I went in and did the reformatting to get the spoilers to still work...

Comment: This also explain why all but the first are "Fathers" - although I think #2 should be "son"